# html5 canvas - How can I stretch text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

In my `html 5` canvas, I draw text (that has to be on 1 line) but it needs to be a constant font size and style and the width of the space I have is also constant. Therefore the text needs to fit in that space, but the problem occurs when the text is too long and goes past the space.

So is there a way I can horizontally stretch/compress text? (like in PhotoShop)

Something like convert it to an image then change the width of the image? Not sure if this is the best way...

Thanks

Comment: you want to stretch/compress it but the text needs to be a constant size?

Comment: it needs to be a constant size before the stretch. For example, the font style has to be 30px Arial, and then if it goes past the boundary, it gets a 80% width re-size.

Comment: @omega: Do you want to only resize if if it doesn't fit, or resize it always to the exact width of the space?

Comment: Only if it doesn't fit, then resize it so it does fit.

Comment: Are you wanting to scale the text, or just horizontally squish it? If you just want to squish it, [fillText has a parameter for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas)

Comment: I want to horizontally squish it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `measureText` to determine the size of the text first, then scale the canvas if needed: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/887/.

```
var text = "foo bar foo bar";
ctx.font = "30pt Arial";

var width = ctx.measureText(text).width;
if(width <= 100) {
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 100);
} else {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(100 / width, 1);
    ctx.fillText(text, 0, 100);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Comment: This does effectively the same thing as providing `maxWidth` as per @MrOBrian suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/888/.

Comment: +1 I didn't knew the scale function of Canvas. This is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to draw your text in another (in memory) canvas and then use drawImage to paste the canvas content in the real destination canvas.

Something like this (let it be parameterizable depending on your needs, here stretching with a ratio of 100 to 80) :

```
var tempimg = document.createElement('canvas');
tempimg.width = 100;
tempimg.height = 10;
oc = tempimg.getContext('2d');
oc.fillText(...)
yourdestcontext.drawImage(tempimg, 0, 0, 100, 10, x, y, 80, 10);
```

Comment: for the width, can I use percentage instead of pixels?

Comment: In this case, as the source is 100px wide, yes. Otherwise you'd have to compute the dest width based on your percentage.